# Numerical integration and interpolation with free parameters

Tags: numerical-integration

I hope you'll be able to give me a hand on my question, I'm stuck and don't know how to make it work.

First of all, I have a table of data pairs (x,f):

```
fdata[a_,b_]:=Table[{x[[i]],f[a,b,c][[i]]},{i,1,Length[x]}];
```

And I want to do an interpolation which will also be dependent on the parameters a, b. Something like

```
fx[a_,b_]:=Interpolation[fdata[a,b]]
```

Then I will use this function inside NDSolve and NIntegrate

```
NIntegrate[1/fx[x,a,b], {x, 0., zlim}]
```

But this last expression gives me this error:

> ```
> The integrand 1/fx[x,0.3,0.001,0.68,2,3,1,4] has evaluated to 
> non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with 
> boundaries {{0.,2}}.
> ```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `fx[a,b][x]` instead of `fx[x,a,b]`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Marius. That was the thing!